# Contenido TextArea en PHP con $_POST

Tags: php, html, formularios

Estoy creando un formulario de prueba el cual quiero que me mande los datos introducidos a un `php`. Me envía el Nombre y el Correo pero el texto introducido en el `TEXTAREA` no me lo envía. Dejo el código

**feedback.html:**

```
<form action="feed.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td >Your Name:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="text" name="name" size="25" maxlength="30" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td >Your Email Address:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><input type="text" name="email" size="25" maxlength="30" />
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Your Feddback:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="feedback" form="usrform"  >
</textarea></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input style="margin-left:-80px;" 
type="submit" value="Send Feddback" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>


</form>
```

**feed.php:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$feedback = $_POST["feedback"];

echo $name . "</br>";
echo $email . "</br>";
echo $feedback . "</br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ¿ Qué es lo que está pasando en este caso ?

Al añadir el atributo `form` dentro de un elemento , le está indicando a que formulario pertenece dicho elemento, esto se hace beneficioso para un caso particular donde los elementos no estén necesariamente dentro del formulario

**Ejm**

```
<form action="feed.php" method="post" id="usrform">
  <!-- más elementos-->
</form>
<textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="feedback" form="usrform"  >
</textarea>
```

Al enviar dicho formulario , se podría pensar que no se está enviando el `textarea` , pero como se añadió el atributo `form` también se envía y se podrá acceder desde el lugar a donde se está enviando.

En su ejemplo está añadiendo el atributo y no hay un elemento `form` con ese id por lo cuál no se envía dicho elemento así se encuentre dentro del `form`.

Para resolver su problema , tiene dos opciones  , remueve el atributo `form` del `textarea` ya que está dentro de las etiquetas `form` y no sería necesario añadirlo , o añade el `id` al formulario con el valor que ya tiene *(usrform)*

```
<form action="feed.php" method="post">
  <textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="feedback"  >
</form>

<form action="feed.php" method="post" id="usrform">
</form>
<textarea rows="6" cols="40" name="feedback" form="usrform"  >
```

> La documentación de dicho atributo está disponible en cada elemento ,
>   como por ejemplo [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/textarea) , [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input) , este atributo está disponible para **`button , fieldset ,input , label, meter, object, output ,select , textarea.`**

Comment: Explique por qué debe quitar ese atributo, citando la documentación, si es posible, para enriquecimiento de todos los viandantes que pasen por esta pregunta. Entonces tendrá mi +1.